# Add CSS component to Qt QML

Tags: css, qt, qml

I am new to QML, so I wanted to ask ..  is it possible to import/convert/use CSS templates in QT ?
because I found many stylish CSS component. more than QML templates.

Answer (score -2):

QML by default allows CSS styling with limited options. The limitations are mentioned [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html).

But if your intention is to add a .css file into the project and make that as a style sheet then there is no default way.

Here is the out of the box [project](https://github.com/Ableton/aqt-stylesheets) with GitHub, which allows direct integration of CSS style sheets into QML. You can refer to the [examples](https://github.com/Ableton/aqt-stylesheets/tree/master/examples) in that project

Comment: Part of your answer is wrong: *QML by default allows CSS styling with limited options. The limitations are mentioned here.* those are only for QTextEdit, the TextEdit item but not for the QML elements: *Qt's text widgets are able to display rich text, specified using a subset of HTML 4 markup. Widgets that use QTextDocument, such as QLabel and QTextEdit, are able to display rich text specified in this way.*